# Footnote with number in margin

Tags: footnotes, marginpar

How can I make a footnote's number appear in the margin, instead of embedded in the main text? I tried

```
\marginpar{ \footnote{ blah } }
```

and the footnote number appears, but not the footnote text.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a normal footnote.\footnote{My footnote text.} 
Next we'll place a note in the margin.\marginpar{Margin note here.}
Can we put a footnote number in the margin, 
with the footnote text at the bottom of the page?\marginpar{\footnote{I hope so!}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I also tried the `marginnote` package instead of `\marginpar`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pair of commands `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\marginfootnote}[1]{\marginpar{\footnotemark}\footnotetext{#1}}
\begin{document}
Can we put a footnote number in the margin, with the footnote text at 
the bottom of the page?\marginfootnote{I hope so!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks! I'm pleased to see it doesn't require huge packages or cryptic commands...

Comment: worked for me but i had to add the package--\usepackage[all]{background}